# How to save the dataframe in scala as a csv ? csv function not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting below error while trying to save the dataframe as a csv file in cloudera

```
scala> df.write.csv("/home/cloudera/Desktop/thakur2")
<console>:31: error: value csv is not a member of
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter
              df.write.csv("/home/cloudera/Desktop/thakur2")
```

Answer (score 0):

csv() method is not available on DataFrameWriter class for spark version <2.0.

If you are using spark version<2.0 on cloudera then you should use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) library.